# No provider for NgModel! while creating Structural directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I created an structural directive. Here is the constructor of that class.

```
constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, public query: NgModel) {
    console.log(this.query)
}
```

If I remove `public query:NgModel`, it works fine. If I add it It throws error.

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for NgModel! (ControlMeta -> NgModel)`

What is the error here?

I did same for normal directive, it is working fine.

Comment: What the error does it throw?

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich, I updated question.`Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for NgModel! (ControlMeta -> NgModel)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to specify `NgModel` as `provider`:

```
@Directive({ 
  selector: '...',
  providers: [NgModel],
  ...
})
```

Comment: Working fine, Thanks, But I didn't understand, why it is not showing error for another normal directive where I did same and showing error only for structural directive?

Comment: It's structural directive. You usually do the same for your custom directives (specify it in `providers` list)

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich should directive DOM should have `[(ngModel)]` directive on that element?

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich, Thanks for your sample.  I added `NgModel` to my `providers` property in my `@Component`.